# Sprintf shows <number: 19> instead of 19 on js.Value

Tags: go, webassembly

In my code I'm getting a `js.Value` that is a simple object `{"Age":19}`

For displaying it, I used:

```golang
data := fmt.Sprintf("Age: %v", value.Get("age"))
fmt.Println(data)
```

But the output was:

```sh
Age: <number: 19>
```

Expected output is:

```sh
Age: 19
```

Once I replaced the `%v` by `%d` to be:

```golang
data := fmt.Sprintf("Age: %v", value.Get("age"))
fmt.Println(data)
```

I got:

```sh
Age: {[] 4626041242239631360 0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`js.Value.Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js#Value.Get) returns a `js.Value` again, and `js.Value` implements `fmt.Stringer` interface. The output you see is the result of calling [`Value.String()`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js#Value.String) on an instance that wraps `js.TypeNumber`

> String returns the value v as a string.
> String is a special case because of Go's String method convention. Unlike the other getters, it does not panic if v's Type is not TypeString. Instead, it returns a string of the **form "" or "<T: V>" where T is v's type and V is a string representation of v's value**.

Use [`Value.Int()`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js#Value.Int) or [`Value.Float()`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js#Value.Float) to unwrap the numerical value:

```
data := fmt.Printf("Age: %d", value.Get("age").Int())
```

---

This instead `{[] 4626041242239631360 0}` is the string representation of the `Value` struct itself with its internals. For reference:

```golang
type Value struct {
    _     [0]func() // uncomparable; to make == not compile
    ref   ref       // identifies a JavaScript value, see ref type
    gcPtr *ref      // used to trigger the finalizer when the Value is not referenced any more
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `js.Value` shows that the result of `Get` is another `Value` struct, and not an integer. So when you print the resulting `js.Value` with %v, it goes to the default formatter for a `js.Value`, which prints the *type* as well as the value.

When you explicitly told it to print it as %d, it prints the Value struct as numbers, which in this case means an empty array a `ref` struct and a `*ref` pointer, as you can see in the code:
https://golang.org/src/syscall/js/js.go

What you probably want is to call the `Int()` method, which returns the value as an integer:

```
data := fmt.Sprintf("Age: %d, value.Get("Age").Int())
fmt.Println(data)
```